# How to parallel execution

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, blocking, nextcord

I am trying to do parallelism with python for my discord bot.

```py
import os
import nest_asyncio
from multiprocessing import Process
from .src.Configs.configs import client
from .src.boot.start import start


nest_asyncio.apply()

def main():
  token = os.environ['TOKEN']
  p1 = Process(target = start)
  p2 = Process(target = client.run, args=[token])
  p1.start()
  p2.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
  
  pass
```

My actual code is the above. Now i am having trouble with the processes, the `client.run` methods raises two errors `EOFError: Ran out of input` and `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'WeakSet.__init__.<locals>._remove'` and the `start()` function which is a `async def start()` raises `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'start' was never awaited`. Any thoughts how can i do this multiprocessing?

Comment: I've done similar to this before but it's kind of scuffed, sometimes the nested asyncio process will just randomly pause. Looking for an answer for this too

Comment: My solution was calling pm2 to run the program. Bad solution, but searching the topic was way more confusing. I cant understand how pm2 programs works, how they can release the eventloop to the terminal. After some months i still dont know how to bypass this, the eventloop hijacks the process no matter what.